# Использование httpclient в asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

Кто сможет мне объяснить почему данная функция иногда мне возвращает `null`:

```
public async Task<T> PostData<T>(string apiFunction, object data) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiFunction, data))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);
            }
            else return new T();
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        return new T();
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Используется в сервисе, который объявлен как синглтон. Вызывается в контроле. Например:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Connect()
{
    ResponseServer responseServer = await _request.PostData<ResponseServer>("connection", userEntity);
    if (responseServer == null) responseServer = new ResponseServer();
}
```

Приходится делать дополнительную проверку на `null`.

Comment: Вы не все ловите эксепшены. Не хватает `catch(Exception)` в самом конце блока catch'ей

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Я подозревал об этом, но думал если бы была эксепшен отличная от тех, которые ловлю, то при отладке она должна была бы отображаться. Но никак не ожидал, что это будет только NullReferenceException.

Comment: По моему по этому: `else return new T();`

Comment: @NewView Не, точно не в этом. new T не будет равно null никогда. Тут что-то другое. Я подозреваю, что и я неправильный ответ дал

Comment: Спорить не буду, но возможно,на мой взгляд, если тип Nullable, хотя конечно конструктор не должен возвращать null

Comment: @NewView При указанных топикстартером условиях (ResponseServer + `where T : new()`)  на практике точно не будет - а за какие-то теоретические конструкции и я не поручусь, мало ли какие извраты компилятор пропустит и в рантайме возможны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, я созрел до ответа.

Давайте во-первых, покажем, что дело не в `else return new T()`, не в отсутствии ещё одного блока catch как я предположил в комментариях ну и заодно накидаем классы, на которых будем моделировать разные ситуации.

Берём linqpad, пишем:

```
void Main()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    var test = myClass.Test<Data>();
    if(test == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("null");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not null");
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class MyClass
{
    public T Test<T>()
        where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Запускаем, смотрим — не null.

Попытка два. Попробуем выкинуть исключение, причём типа, который мы не обрабатываем:

```
public T Test<T>()
    where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Всё логично — мы получаем необработанное исключение. Тоже не вариант.

Подключим Json и попробуем посмотреть что будет в результате у нас Null:

```
public T Test<T>()
    where T : new()
{
    try {
        string data = null;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Снова не null, так как Json.Net выкинет ArgumentException, которое отловится на catch.

Но вот если мы попробуем указать, что data — пустая строка, то мы получим null:

```
public T Test<T>()
    where T : new()
{
    string data = string.Empty;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
}
```

Вот оно и найдено ваше условие. Вы получаете из http client'а пустую строку, а в результате Json.Net выкидывает вам Null.

Comment: Аплодисменты, одназначно!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!